# Does it matter the order of amplification and rms squaring?

Tags: amplifier, rms

If in a circuit a signal is first amplified and then its rms value is found, would we get the same result if first the signal is rms found and then amplified?

Comment: Can you be clearer in your question as to what you mean. particularly I'm confused about what you mean by "RMS squared".

Comment: As long as you don't run into dynamic range issues.  (having the signal clip because of too much gain.)

Comment: yes i meant "rms value found" hope the editors change the topic name for me.

Comment: @gbulmer I disagree with the  edit you have made - in cases like this you should restate what you think the op means in your answer as I have done - I have a different (as possibly more valid) version but that's the point - it's subjective.

Comment: @Andyaka - Agreed. Reverted.

Comment: i meant this: Case1: an input first goes to rms circuit and then amplifier; we measure the output. Case2: an input first goes to amplifier and then rms circuit; we measure the output. will the outputs measured be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your question as meaning that if instead of feeding a real signal into the amplifier you fed into the input a DC level representative of its RMS value, will the output DC level be the RMS of the amplified signal.

If this interpretation is correct then theoretically, on a perfect amplifier with no DC-offsets to worry about and providing the amplifier is DC coupled in its stages then the output DC voltage would be OK but there are a lot of things that could make this wrong.

For instance if the real signal were somewhat attenuated by frequency shaping circuits (even just a regular 3dB roll-off as seen in op-amp circuits) then the real signal at the output may be significantly less than what you'd expect. This of course means the DC version would give a falsely high representation of the RMS.

This is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make a difference. RMS is a linear transformation itself, so it doesn't matter, provided you multiply the RMS and Gain as well.

Comment: Your two sentences are in conflict. It seems that the OP has perhaps changed?

Comment: He seems to be answering the title in the first sentence.

Comment: I thought the OP meant multiplying the RMS value as well. RMS(A*s)=A*RMS(s)

Comment: My bad, your wording caught me out so I misinterpreted what you were saying.

Comment: @MikeSparkn - "I thought the OP meant multiplying the RMS value as well. RMS(A*s)=A*RMS(s)" Ah! Good point. I'll try to revert my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The operation "its rms value is found" is typically a measurement; *it should not change the signal in any way*.

If you meant measuring the rms value of the signal before and after amplification, then in general the value will not be the same. Measuring before amplification, and after amplification will only give an equal answer with unity gain. In all other cases they are different.

Comment: In other words, \$A(x^2) \neq (Ax)^2\$, unless A = 1.

Comment: no i meant this: Case1: an input first goes to rms circuit and then amplifier; we measure the output. Case2: an input first goes to amplifier and then rms circuit; we measure the output. will the outputs measured be the same?

Comment: @user16307 - So you wanted Andy aka's interpretation. I found Mike Spark's "RMS(A*s)=A*RMS(s)" comment helpful. I still find the phrase "rms value is found" misleading. I would prefer "transformed to its RMS value", or "converted to its RMS value", or even "transformed to its DC RMS value". I'm glad you got the help you needed.